# DDay iCal RecurrenceId

Tags: recurring-events, dday

I am actually using the Telerik kendo scheduler, instead of an iCal file, but I need to display an occurrence list in a manner other than the schedulers agenda list and the mappings between the schedule object and an ical object are similar so I figured I would use DDay.

Creating an iCalendar object and loading in the schedule table I have the code working where I can build the occurrence list and filter out events deleted from the series. Where I am having problems is where an event was modified in the series.

With the way the data is stored in the db when a modified event in a series is created it creates a new record and populates the **RecurrenceId** field with the original record's event Id.

Seems simple enough just match against id fields, right? Problem is the **RecurrenceId** in DDay iCal is an IDateTime and not an int. I am not sure how to process it because we have a lot of events that start/end at the same time so grabbing the original start/end does not seems viable. Unless I am misunderstanding what is actually happening.

I did figure out a convoluted way to handle a modified event if it is the only modified event for the master event in the occurrence. But this method does not account for an occurrence series that might include the master event and multiple modified events off of the master.

I guess one possible solution would be to build 2 lists from the scheduler table one that has only modified recurring events and the other master events.

Then as I am processing the occurrences I do a check against each occurrence to see if it exists in the modified events list. If so update the occurrence accordingly.  Seems like a very kludgy solution however. Even if it would address all the modified scenarios. I think I am missing something in the library that would handle this.

As always any help that can be provided on this issue would be appreciated.

Thanks,
Chris

Answer (score 0):

It seems that my test set data was screwed up. The way it appears that it works is the master event will have a recurrence exception. So when you make a call to get an occurrences if an exception is in that range the master record will be skipped/filtered and the modified event for the series will remain. Additionally, if the event in the occurrence range was deleted then the event will not appear in the occurrence range.

There were some errors in my test data set which made it look like there needed to be an additional filter step.